# Time of day of Chicxulub impact

Tags: geology, earth-history, impacts, cretaceous, impact-craters

Is there any known evidence about what the local time of day of the Chicxulub impact was (at the very least, whether the impactor struck during day or night)?

If there is not any such known evidence, then is there any known form/mechanism of scientific evidence that we might be able to find or examine that could reveal the local time of day?

Comment: My first thought was "do we really care"... but honestly it's quite an interesting question.  In addition to information around the crater itself, which is the first thought that comes to mind... thinking more that if we know the source region for the asteroid, we may know the time of day by the direction it would've been facing... if the impact is relatively straight on (with the speeds involved, can't imagine any complex paths, though there could still be a fair acute angle change by gravitation???)  Interesting question indeed!

Comment: Similar question at Astronomy SE: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/14041/34513